# Blackberry - problem in sending mail

Tags: email, blackberry

While trying to send mail I've received error:

> sendingfailedexception:MAIL_API:no rim
>   service record

Code:

```
      try
      {
            Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance();
            if(s == null)
            {
               String errMsg = "Unabled to send email message.\n";
               Dialog.alert(errMsg);
               bCanSend = false;
            }                  
            else
            {
               bCanSend = true;


               _emailTo =" poomalai@i-waves.com";
               _emailBody = "emailBody";

               emailTransport = Session.getTransport();
              // msgStore = Session.waitForDefaultSession().getStore();
           //    folderList = msgStore.list(Folder.SENT);
           //    outFolder = folderList[0];
           //    msg = new Message(outFolder);
               msg = new Message();

            }

      }
      catch(Exception nse)
      {
           System.out.println(nse.toString());
      } 

  try
  {

    System.out.println("SendEmail :: running");
    if(bCanSend == true)
    {

            Address [] addresses = new Address[1];
            addresses[0] = new Address(_emailTo, _emailTo);
            msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);
            msg.setSubject("IBM Calendar Share!");
            msg.setContent(_emailBody);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception caught trying to send email: " + 
               e.toString());
               Dialog.inform(e.toString());
        }
        try
        {
            emailTransport.send(msg);


        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception caught trying to send email: " + 
               e.toString());
               Dialog.inform(e.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this error on devices which have no email account setup on them. e.g. there is a data connection, a BBM connection, and the guy uses gmail - but does has not configured an email account in the OS.

I also call

```
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance();
```

This does not return `null` - so looking at your code, you assumed you can send. But the call to `Transport.send(msg)` fails because the account is not setup.

Edit: I have read that this error can also come up if you try to set the "from" address to an invalid account.

Catch this exception (like you have) and tell the user to set up a valid email account before retrying.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send mail from the simulator.

Comment: In device also i got an error of.... sendingfailedexception:MAIL_API:no mail service record... like that....

Comment: sorry that one: no rmi servic record

Comment: still i am struggling to complete email sending concept please anyone help me..........

Comment: The simulator should not give that error - mine does not. The mail will not send unless you run the mail simulator, but the exception does not occur afaik.